# numerical techniques of integration.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am working on some past exam questions of integration and i came across this question. Can any body solve & explain this in detail to me. Thanks

using FTC we Know 
$$\int_1^3 \frac{1}{x^2} = \left | \frac{-1}{x} \right |_{1}^{3} = \frac{2}{3} $$

to test out the numerical techniques we can still apply them to an integral like this and check how accurate they are.

(1) Calculate  for this integral. $$T_4,S_4 $$

(2) use the error estimate for $$T_n $$ to estimate $$\lvert E(T_4)\rvert$$

[image]

Here is the whole question.....

Comment: who is $T^4$, $S^4$? Add some informations and *show your work*.. What have you tried? Where do you have problems?

Comment: i dont understand this question thats why i posted it here. if i could understand i would have posted some working atleast.

Comment: We can help you understand how to solve a problem, but for this we need the full problem statement, including an explanation of any nonstandard notation. Unfortunately this is not psychics.se.

Comment: u can see the picture now. i have posted it.

Comment: Can you please also post the definitions of $T_4$ and $S_4$?

Comment: Still, it is not clear what $T_4$ and $S_4$ mean. Why not just tell us what they are? Also, what does FTC stand for? Unless you explain this and show some work your question is about to be closed.

Comment: FTC is a commonly used abbreviation for the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. Ross Millikan's answer has a reasonable guess as to what $T_4$ and $S_4$ are, but that should definitely be defined in the question.

Comment: You forgot $G_4$ which evaluates to approximately 0.666449

Comment: You were not even able to reproduce the integral evaluation correctly from the problem statement ! What you wrote is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

For $T_4$ I believe you are expected to divide $[1,3]$ into four intervals and apply the trapezoidal rule.  For $S_4$ you are to divide it into four or eight and use Simpson's rule.  The uncertainty here comes from the fact that one piece of Simpson's rule has two subintervals.  Whoever posed the problem owes you that answer.  In any text there will be an error estimate for the trapezoidal rule, which you are supposed to look up and compute.  You can then see how close the actual error is to the limit.

Answer (score 0):

$\color{red}{\text{NOTE: Please next time add information to your question and explain the different terms appearing.}}$

---

**CTR Theorem:** Let $f\in C^2[a,b]$, $h=(b-a)/n$, and $x_j=a+jh$, for each $j=0,1,\dots,n$. There exists a $\xi\in[a,b]$ for which the **Composite Trapezoidal Rule** for $n$ subintervals can be written with its error term as
$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\frac{h}{2}\left [ f(a)+2\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}f(x_j)+f(b) \right ]-\frac{b-a}{12}h^2f''(\xi(x))$$

**CSR Theorem:** Let $f\in C^4[a,b]$, $n$ be even, $h=(b-a)/n$, and $x_j=a+jh$, for each $j=0,1,\dots,n$. There exists a $\xi\in[a,b]$ for which the **Composite Simpson's Rule** for $n$ subintervals can be written with its error term as
$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\frac{h}{3}\left [ f(a)+2\sum_{j=1}^{(n/2)-1}f(x_{2j})+4\sum_{j=1}^{n/2}f(x_{2j-1})+f(b) \right ]-\frac{b-a}{180}h^4f^{(4)}(\xi(x))$$

---

### Solution:

**(a):** For both $T_4$ and $S_4$, we have $n=4$, which means the step size is $h=\frac{b-a}{b}=\frac{3-1}{4}=0.5$. Moreover, $x_j=a+jh=1+j0.5$ for each $j=0,1,\dots,4$. Therefore the nodal points are:
$$x_0=1=a,x_1=1.5,x_2=2,x_3=2.5,x_4=3$$

- $T_4$:

\begin{align}
\int_{1}^{3}f(x)dx&\simeq \frac{1}{4}\left [ f(1)+2\sum_{j=1}^{3}f(x_j)+f(3) \right ] \\
 & = \frac{1}{4}\left [ f(1)+2\left \{ f(x_1)+f(x_2)+f(x_3) \right \}+f(3) \right ]\\
 & = \frac{1}{4}\left [ f(1)+2\left \{ f(1.5)+f(2)+f(2.5) \right \}+f(3) \right ]\\
 & = \frac{1}{4}\left [ 1+2\left \{ \frac{4}{9}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{4}{25} \right \}+\frac{1}{9} \right ] \\
& = \frac{141}{200} \\
 & = 0.70500
\end{align}

- $S_4$:

\begin{align}
\int_{1}^{3}f(x)dx&\simeq \frac{1}{6}\left [ f(1)+2\sum_{j=1}^{1}f(x_{2j})+4\sum_{j=1}^{2}f(x_{2j-1})+f(3) \right ] \\
 & = \frac{1}{6}\left [ f(1)+2f(x_2)+4\left \{ f(x_1)+f(x_3) \right \}+f(3) \right ]\\
 & = \frac{1}{6}\left [ f(1)+2f(2)+4\left \{ f(1.5)+f(2.5) \right \}+f(3) \right ]\\
 & = \frac{1}{6}\left [ 1+2\cdot \frac{1}{4}+4\left \{ \frac{4}{9}+\frac{4}{25} \right \}+\frac{1}{9} \right ] \\
& = \frac{1813}{2700} \\
 & \approx 0.67148
\end{align}

**(b):** The error term for the CTR is 
$$E=-\frac{b-a}{12}h^2f''(\xi(x)),\xi\in[a,b]$$
Then for $n=4$ and $a=1$,$b=3$, we get
$$E=-\frac{-1}{24}\cdot \frac{6}{\xi^4}=-\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{\xi^4},\xi\in[1,3]$$
Since $\xi$ is unknown, we can only hope for a bound of the error. This can be easily done as follows
$$\left |E  \right |=\left |-\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{\xi^4}  \right |=\frac{1}{4}\cdot \left | \frac{1}{\xi^4} \right |\leq \frac{1}{4}\cdot \max_{1\leq \xi\leq 3}\left \{ \frac{1}{\xi^4} \right \}=\frac{1}{4}\cdot 1=\frac{1}{4}=0.25$$

**(c):** We need to find the number of subintervals $n$ that would ensure that our answer is accurate to $4$ decimals place. Let us assume that we invoke rounding in our approximations. A measure of this error is $\epsilon =0.5\times 10^{-k}$, where $k$ is the number of decimal places. Therefore \epsilon =0.5\times 10^{-4}. Moreover, the error term for the CSR is
$$E=-\frac{b-a}{180}h^4f^{(4)}(\xi(x)),\xi\in[a,b]$$
Then for $n=4$ and $a=1$,$b=3$, we get
$$E=-\frac{b-a}{180}h^4f^{(4)}(\xi(x))=-\frac{b-a}{180}\left ( \frac{b-a}{n} \right )^4f^{(4)}(\xi(x))=-\frac{\left ( b-a \right )^5}{180}\cdot \frac{1}{n^4}\cdot f^{(4)}(\xi(x))$$
or
$$E=-\frac{8}{45}\cdot \frac{1}{n^4}\cdot \frac{120}{\xi^6}=-\frac{64}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{n^4}\cdot \frac{1}{\xi^6}$$
To meet 4 decimal accuracy, we require
$$\left |E\right|=\left|-\frac{64}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{n^4}\cdot \frac{1}{\xi^6}  \right |=\frac{64}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{n^4}\cdot \frac{1}{\xi^6}\leq 0.5\times 10^{-4}$$
Solving for $n$
$$n^4\geq \frac{64}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{\xi^4}\cdot \frac{1}{0.5\times 10^{-4}}\geq \frac{64}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{1^6}\cdot \frac{1}{0.5\times 10^{-4}}$$
Taking the fourth-root
$$n\geq \sqrt[4]{\frac{64}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{0.5\times 10^{-4}}}=25.5577$$
which implies that we need at least
$$n=26$$